# Running a function more than once changes an array inside the function

Tags: javascript

This next example function works just fine:

```
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function insertAndShift(arr, number) {
  const cutOut = arr.splice(-number);
  return [...cutOut, ...arr];
}

console.log('Output: ', insertAndShift(data, 2));
// Output: [4,5,1,2,3]
```

However, when I call the function another time, I suddenly get a wrong response:

```
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function insertAndShift(arr, number) {

  // The next starting array should be [1,2,3,4,5] on both occasions.
  // However, on the second occasion it will only be [1,2,3].
  // Which was the array in the first time the function was called.
  console.log('arr: ', arr);

  const cutOut = arr.splice(-number);
  return [...cutOut, ...arr];
}

console.log('Output: ', insertAndShift(data, 2));
// Output: [4,5,1,2,3]

console.log('Output: ', insertAndShift(data, 3));
// Output: [1,2,3]
// Should be: [3,4,5,1,2]
```

Is this a scoping issue? Or what is exactly happening here?

Comment: [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) mutates the array. So after your first call `data` has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript, all, non primitive, variable are passed "by reference", which mean you can modify a variable from inside a function. This is where you need to be careful. Usually, you would clone your array before doing anything with it, this way, the original array won't be affected by your mutations.

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function insertAndShift(arr, number) {
  let clonedArray = [...arr];
  // The next starting array should be [1,2,3,4,5] on both occasions.
  // However, on the second occasion it will only be [1,2,3].
  // Which was the array in the first time the function was called.

  const cutOut = clonedArray.splice(-number);
  return [...cutOut, ...clonedArray];
}

console.log('Output: ', insertAndShift(data, 2));

console.log('Output: ', insertAndShift(data, 3));
```

Comment: Nice! Ty. Would you happen to have an article/blogpost regarding this specific topic? Or a keyword I should search for?

Comment: not all variables are passed by reference ... eg primitive values.

Comment: @NinaScholz you are right, i've edited my answer for accuracy.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using let instead of const for the clonedArray?

Comment: @Remi you can check out [this article](https://slemgrim.com/mutate-or-not-to-mutate/) I have not red it in it's entirity but it's seams pretty accurate.

Comment: @Remi in this case, no. You could use const , since you are never re-assigning it's value.

Answer (score 2):

Beside of cloning an array, you could take parts directly with [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and build a new array - without using mutating [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```js
function insertAndShift(array, number) {
    return [...array.slice(-number), ...array.slice(0, -number)];
}

const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(...insertAndShift(data, 2)); // [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
console.log(...insertAndShift(data, 3)); // [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Very nice. I will accept the answer of Nicolas since that answers my question on the 'change of the variable'. But upvoted yours since this is a nice addition to the function.